# Universal (any ContentType) ITaggerProvider

Tags: c#, visual-studio, content-type, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

Is there a way to register universal ITaggerProvider implementation? E.g. not bound to a specific content type with ContentType attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always have a ContentType attribute, but you can just declare your tagger to operate against the "text" content type which will apply to all normal content types.

```
[ContentType("text")]
```